# Android: Providing recent search suggestions without searchable activity?

Tags: java, android, searchview

I have an ActionBar SearchView and I am successfully able to make searches with it. The android documentation does not explain how to implement search suggestions. I do not want to have a searchable activity.

This is my search code:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_add_song, menu);
        final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.song_search).getActionView();
        searchView.setFocusable(true);
        searchView.setIconified(false);
        final AddSongActivity activity = this;
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                // Do nothing
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                // Clear SearchView
                searchView.clearFocus();
                // Begin Spotify Search
                TextView notice = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.search_notice);
                URL url;
                try {
                    url = new URL("http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/track.json?q=" + URLEncoder.encode(query,"UTF-8"));
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    notice.setText("Malformed Search");
                    notice.setHeight(noticeHeight);
                    return true;
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    notice.setText("Unsupported Encoding. Maybe a problem with your device.");
                    notice.setHeight(noticeHeight);
                    return true;
                }
                new SearchDownload(url, activity).execute();
                notice.setText("Loading Tracks");
                notice.setHeight(noticeHeight);
                Log.i("infodb","" + noticeHeight);
                return true;
            }
        });
```

This works for searching but I have no idea to implement recent search query suggestions. How do I go about doing this?

Thank you.

Comment: Not sure if you missed this in your googling but the search docs are pretty darn good: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html#SearchSuggestions

Comment: Forgive me if I am wrong. But aren't you leaking a cursor every time you step into onQueryTextChange?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Ok, I spent my time for this. I make my own **simple** suggestion implementation from `SQLiteDatabase`.

We will create 3 classes like the following

1. `MainActivity` - for test of `SearchView` suggestion from database
2. `SuggestionDatabase` - this will store your recent search keyword.
3. `SuggestionSimpleCursorAdapter` - this is a subclass of `SimpleCursorAdapter`. I'll explain why I make this class instead of using `SimpleCursorAdapter`.

The codes

```
// MainActivity.java

public class MainActivity 
    extends Activity
    implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener,
                SearchView.OnSuggestionListener
{

    private SuggestionsDatabase database;
    private SearchView searchView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        database = new SuggestionsDatabase(this);
        searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchView1);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this); 
        searchView.setOnSuggestionListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSuggestionSelect(int position) {

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSuggestionClick(int position) {

        SQLiteCursor cursor = (SQLiteCursor) searchView.getSuggestionsAdapter().getItem(position);
        int indexColumnSuggestion = cursor.getColumnIndex( SuggestionsDatabase.FIELD_SUGGESTION);

        searchView.setQuery(cursor.getString(indexColumnSuggestion), false);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        long result = database.insertSuggestion(query);
        return result != -1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

        Cursor cursor = database.getSuggestions(newText);
        if(cursor.getCount() != 0)
        {
            String[] columns = new String[] {SuggestionsDatabase.FIELD_SUGGESTION };
            int[] columnTextId = new int[] { android.R.id.text1};

            SuggestionSimpleCursorAdapter simple = new SuggestionSimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, cursor,
                    columns , columnTextId
                    , 0);

            searchView.setSuggestionsAdapter(simple);
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

How it works

1. When user taps the search button, the `onQueryTextSubmit()` will be triggered and then the search keyword will be saved in our database. Let's say we submit a keyword "Hello"
2. If the user writes a string for example "Hel" or "H" in `SearchView` the `onQueryTextChange()` will be called and then we search this keyword in `SQLiteDatabase` (`SuggestionDatabase`). If "Hel" or "H" matches "Hello" , display the results of query by setting the returned Cursor in `SuggestionSimpleCursorAdapter` and then set this adapter in `SearchView`. Here's the picture.

[image]
3. Ofcourse we will tap the suggestion which is "Hello", `onSuggestionClick(int position)` will be called for that. We get the `SQLiteCursor` object from the `SearchView`'s adapter (`SuggestionSimpleCursorAdapter`) and get the Suggestion text from it, set the suggestion text in `SearchView` object

```
SQLiteCursor cursor = (SQLiteCursor) searchView.getSuggestionsAdapter().getItem(position);
int indexColumnSuggestion = cursor.getColumnIndex( SuggestionsDatabase.FIELD_SUGGESTION);
searchView.setQuery(cursor.getString(indexColumnSuggestion), false);
```

If we use `SimpleCursorAdapter` it also works properly but let's say we have this scenario

1. If We run this program in smartphone and type the keyword "Hel", the suggestion will appear properly.

[image]

2. What if We rotate the screen in landscape? It will switch in Full Screen mode and you can still type the keyword.

What will happen in suggestion? Let's take a look.

[image]

See the weird suggestion? How we solve that? By overriding the `convertToString(Cursor cursor)` which returns a `CharSequence`

```
 // SuggestionSimpleCursorAdapter.java
public class SuggestionSimpleCursorAdapter
    extends SimpleCursorAdapter
{

    public SuggestionSimpleCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,
            String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to);
    }

    public SuggestionSimpleCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,
            String[] from, int[] to, int flags) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to, flags);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence convertToString(Cursor cursor) {

        int indexColumnSuggestion = cursor.getColumnIndex(SuggestionsDatabase.FIELD_SUGGESTION);

        return cursor.getString(indexColumnSuggestion);
    }


}
```

By overriding `convertToString(Cursor cursor)` , here's the result

[image]

And here's the database

```
// SuggestionDatabase.java
public class SuggestionsDatabase {

  public static final String DB_SUGGESTION = "SUGGESTION_DB";
  public final static String TABLE_SUGGESTION = "SUGGESTION_TB";
  public final static String FIELD_ID = "_id";
  public final static String FIELD_SUGGESTION = "suggestion";

  private SQLiteDatabase db;
  private Helper helper;

  public SuggestionsDatabase(Context context) {

    helper = new Helper(context, DB_SUGGESTION, null, 1);
    db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
  }

  public long insertSuggestion(String text)
  {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(FIELD_SUGGESTION, text);
    return db.insert(TABLE_SUGGESTION, null, values);
  }

  public Cursor getSuggestions(String text)
  {
    return db.query(TABLE_SUGGESTION, new String[] {FIELD_ID, FIELD_SUGGESTION}, 
            FIELD_SUGGESTION+" LIKE '"+ text +"%'", null, null, null, null);
  }


    private class Helper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
    {

    public Helper(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory,
            int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_SUGGESTION+" ("+
                    FIELD_ID+" integer primary key autoincrement, "+FIELD_SUGGESTION+" text);");
        Log.d("SUGGESTION", "DB CREATED");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

  }

}
```

I hope this answer is useful to other programmers alot. :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I understand how to operate a database but how do I display the results as search suggestions?

Comment: That appears to be one mighty excellent answer! I will try to implement this now!

Comment: Ok, that's brilliant! It's not perfect yet (style issues, ordering of suggestions) but it provides suggestions! This is exactly what I wanted. The main change I made was making the database class a subclass of SQLiteOpenHelper. The bounty and accepted answer goes gladly to you. :-)

Comment: Duplicate suggestions can be fixed by `FIELD_SUGGESTION + " TEXT UNIQUE ON CONFLICT REPLACE` and I can order the results by descending id to get the latest queries.

Comment: do you know how to make the suggestions appear below the view? 
BTW great answer, very helpfull

Comment: I get NPE at searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

Comment: Guys, sorry for trivial question, didn't get how to fix duplicate suggestion. Please, couldn't you write whole query for that and where? Thanks beforehand!

Comment: For comparison, see blog post "Android SearchView integration with a custom data provider" http://ramannanda.blogspot.com/2014/10/android-searchview-integration-with.html

Answer (score 5):

My need was even more simplistic - I didn't require a database, as I had the suggestions I many want to show contained in an ArrayList.

Here's an example implementation:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.MatrixCursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.widget.SearchView;
import android.widget.SearchView.OnQueryTextListener;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ActivityTest extends Activity implements OnQueryTextListener {

    private static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    private static final String COLUMN_TERM = "term";
    private static final String DEFAULT = "default";

    private SearchManager searchManager;
    private SearchView searchView;
    private MenuItem searchMenuItem;
    private SuggestAdapter suggestionsAdapter;
    private final ArrayList<String> suggestionsArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    private final ArrayList<String> dummyArray = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Create some dummy entries
        dummyArray.add("apples");
        dummyArray.add("oranges");
        dummyArray.add("bananas");
        dummyArray.add("pears");
        dummyArray.add("plums");

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        searchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);

        searchView = (SearchView) searchMenuItem.getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

        final MatrixCursor matrixCursor = getCursor(suggestionsArray);
        suggestionsAdapter = new SuggestAdapter(this, matrixCursor, suggestionsArray);
        searchView.setSuggestionsAdapter(suggestionsAdapter);
        suggestionsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(final String newText) {

        suggestionsArray.clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < dummyArray.size(); i++) {

            if (dummyArray.get(i).contains(newText)) {
                suggestionsArray.add(dummyArray.get(i));
            }
        }

        final MatrixCursor matrixCursor = getCursor(suggestionsArray);
        suggestionsAdapter = new SuggestAdapter(this, matrixCursor, suggestionsArray);
        searchView.setSuggestionsAdapter(suggestionsAdapter);
        suggestionsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(final String query) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    private class SuggestAdapter extends CursorAdapter implements OnClickListener {

        private final ArrayList<String> mObjects;
        private final LayoutInflater mInflater;
        private TextView tvSearchTerm;

        public SuggestAdapter(final Context ctx, final Cursor cursor, final ArrayList<String> mObjects) {
            super(ctx, cursor, 0);

            this.mObjects = mObjects;
            this.mInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        @Override
        public View newView(final Context ctx, final Cursor cursor, final ViewGroup parent) {
            final View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_search, parent, false);

            tvSearchTerm = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvSearchTerm);

            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public void bindView(final View view, final Context ctx, final Cursor cursor) {

            tvSearchTerm = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvSearchTerm);

            final int position = cursor.getPosition();

            if (cursorInBounds(position)) {

                final String term = mObjects.get(position);
                tvSearchTerm.setText(term);

                view.setTag(position);
                view.setOnClickListener(this);

            } else {
                // Something went wrong
            }
        }

        private boolean cursorInBounds(final int position) {
            return position < mObjects.size();
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(final View view) {

            final int position = (Integer) view.getTag();

            if (cursorInBounds(position)) {

                final String selected = mObjects.get(position);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), selected, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                // Do something

            } else {
                // Something went wrong
            }
        }
    }

    private MatrixCursor getCursor(final ArrayList<String> suggestions) {

        final String[] columns = new String[] { COLUMN_ID, COLUMN_TERM };
        final Object[] object = new Object[] { 0, DEFAULT };

        final MatrixCursor matrixCursor = new MatrixCursor(columns);

        for (int i = 0; i < suggestions.size(); i++) {

            object[0] = i;
            object[1] = suggestions.get(i);

            matrixCursor.addRow(object);
        }

        return matrixCursor;
    }
}
```

In my actual code, I have a custom Interface which populates the ArrayList with dynamic terms fetched from a Server. You would update the dataset in this way:

```
@Override
public void onDataReceived(final ArrayList<String> results) {

    suggestionsArray.clear();
    suggestionsArray.addAll(results);

    final MatrixCursor matrixCursor = getCursor(suggestionsArray);
    suggestionsAdapter = new SuggestAdapter(this, matrixCursor, suggestionsArray);
    searchView.setSuggestionsAdapter(suggestionsAdapter);
    suggestionsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

I found that not initialising an empty cursor or re-creating it every time caused issues.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry for the ping @brandall just wondered what the XML for R.layout.list_item_search looks like?

Comment: omg I was searching for a working solution for DAYS until I found your code. It works like a charm! thanks so much for that.

Answer (score 4):

In the `MainActivity` class from above in `onCreate method` use this code first

```
AutoCompleteTextView search_text = (AutoCompleteTextView) searchView.findViewById(searchView.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, null));
search_text.setThreshold(1);
```

This `setThreshold(1)` means it can search the text from one character as well now.

Answer (score -1):

There is one issue i notice in the above approach.

When the user enters just one character (eg `"H"`), after getting the entries from the DB and setting the adapter to the searchView via `searchView.setSuggestionsAdapter(<adapter>)`, the drop down list is not shown.

Only after entering a second character (eg `" ", "a"`), the suggestion list gets displayed.
Is anybody else observing this behavior ?

Comment: Yes, I'm getting the same behaviour. Still trying to nail where the problem is.

Comment: Have you figured out what the issue is?

Comment: `AutoCompleteTextView.setThreshold(0)` will fix your issue