# SearchView on an activity extending ExpandableListActivity

Tags: android, search

I can't seem to make the `SearchView` work on this setup (or the search widget either). The `SearchView.onQueryTextListener` does not work as well as much of the solutions I found here.

FYI, I am aware of the searchable.xml and the meta tag for the manifest to make my activity searchable. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You can use searchview without using Searchable activity. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13733460/android-providing-recent-search-suggestions-without-searchable-activity)