# XML ressouces for: Android: Providing recent search suggestions without searchable activity?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-actionbar, searchview

in [Android: Providing recent search suggestions without searchable activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13733460/android-providing-recent-search-suggestions-without-searchable-activity)
user brandall posted the following solution (at the bottom of the post):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.MatrixCursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.widget.SearchView;
import android.widget.SearchView.OnQueryTextListener;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ActivityTest extends Activity implements OnQueryTextListener {

    private static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    private static final String COLUMN_TERM = "term";
    private static final String DEFAULT = "default";

    private SearchManager searchManager;
    private SearchView searchView;
    private MenuItem searchMenuItem;
    private SuggestAdapter suggestionsAdapter;
    private final ArrayList<String> suggestionsArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    private final ArrayList<String> dummyArray = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Create some dummy entries
        dummyArray.add("apples");
        dummyArray.add("oranges");
        dummyArray.add("bananas");
        dummyArray.add("pears");
        dummyArray.add("plums");

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        searchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);

        searchView = (SearchView) searchMenuItem.getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

        final MatrixCursor matrixCursor = getCursor(suggestionsArray);
        suggestionsAdapter = new SuggestAdapter(this, matrixCursor, suggestionsArray);
        searchView.setSuggestionsAdapter(suggestionsAdapter);
        suggestionsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(final String newText) {

        suggestionsArray.clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < dummyArray.size(); i++) {

            if (dummyArray.get(i).contains(newText)) {
                suggestionsArray.add(dummyArray.get(i));
            }
        }

        final MatrixCursor matrixCursor = getCursor(suggestionsArray);
        suggestionsAdapter = new SuggestAdapter(this, matrixCursor, suggestionsArray);
        searchView.setSuggestionsAdapter(suggestionsAdapter);
        suggestionsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(final String query) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    private class SuggestAdapter extends CursorAdapter implements OnClickListener {

        private final ArrayList<String> mObjects;
        private final LayoutInflater mInflater;
        private TextView tvSearchTerm;

        public SuggestAdapter(final Context ctx, final Cursor cursor, final ArrayList<String> mObjects) {
            super(ctx, cursor, 0);

            this.mObjects = mObjects;
            this.mInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        @Override
        public View newView(final Context ctx, final Cursor cursor, final ViewGroup parent) {
            final View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_search, parent, false);

            tvSearchTerm = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvSearchTerm);

            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public void bindView(final View view, final Context ctx, final Cursor cursor) {

            tvSearchTerm = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvSearchTerm);

            final int position = cursor.getPosition();

            if (cursorInBounds(position)) {

                final String term = mObjects.get(position);
                tvSearchTerm.setText(term);

                view.setTag(position);
                view.setOnClickListener(this);

            } else {
                // Something went wrong
            }
        }

        private boolean cursorInBounds(final int position) {
            return position < mObjects.size();
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(final View view) {

            final int position = (Integer) view.getTag();

            if (cursorInBounds(position)) {

                final String selected = mObjects.get(position);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), selected, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                // Do something

            } else {
                // Something went wrong
            }
        }
    }

    private MatrixCursor getCursor(final ArrayList<String> suggestions) {

        final String[] columns = new String[] { COLUMN_ID, COLUMN_TERM };
        final Object[] object = new Object[] { 0, DEFAULT };

        final MatrixCursor matrixCursor = new MatrixCursor(columns);

        for (int i = 0; i < suggestions.size(); i++) {

            object[0] = i;
            object[1] = suggestions.get(i);

            matrixCursor.addRow(object);
        }

        return matrixCursor;
    }
}
```

As I am a complete novice, how would the appropiate XML resource files look like?

Thanks!

Presently I have the following res files:

***layout folder:***

**activity_activity_test.xml:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".ActivityTest">

    <TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/status_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**list_item_search.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</LinearLayout>
```

***menu folder:***

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/search"
        android:title="search_title"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />
</menu>
```

**menu_activity_test.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".ActivityTest">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings" android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100" app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

Comment: Please read the relevant [training section](http://developer.android.com/training/search/setup.html) in the documentation.

Comment: @corsair992: this is WITH searchable configuration. Therefore unfortunately not the right solution.

Comment: What "appropiate XML resource files" are you asking about? The menu resource is shown in the first section.

Comment: If I do that, I just get an empty screen in the emulator...

Comment: So you don't have an action bar in the activity? In that case, that's what you need to work on adding.

Comment: I put my present XMLs in the question. Where do I have to add the action bar?

Comment: The action bar should appear by default unless you have disabled it in the theme, or you are on a lower API level than Honeycomb, in which case you need to use the appcompat library with `ActionBarActivity`.

Comment: Unfortunately, my knowledge is too low to follow your advice... :-(

Therefore, only suitable XML files would help me here. Sorry for my degree of beginnerness :-(