# suggestion list is empty in android searchview

Tags: android

I create a simple searchview in android.

**When i type a text in searchview the suggestion list shown as empty list**

My code
**res/xml/searchable.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/search"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint">   
</searchable>
```

**values/strings.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">SearchViewDemo</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="search">Search</string>
    <string name="search_hint">Search the dictionary</string>
    <string name="title_activity_searchable">SearchableActivity</string>

</resources>
```

**menu/searchable.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

   <item
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:title="@string/search"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"/>

</menu>
```

**layout/activity_searchable.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".SearchableActivity" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.searchviewdemo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.searchviewdemo.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.searchviewdemo.SearchableActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_searchable" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
                android:value="com.example.searchviewdemo.SearchableActivity"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable"></meta-data>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**SearchableActivity.java**

```
package com.example.searchviewdemo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.MatrixCursor;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SearchView;
import android.widget.SearchView.OnQueryTextListener;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;

public class SearchableActivity extends Activity {

    private List<String> items=null;
    private Menu menu;

    ListView mylist;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_searchable);
        //loaddata();

        items=new ArrayList<String>();

        Bundle extras=getIntent().getExtras();
        if(extras!=null)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<7;i++)
            {
                items.add(extras.getString("values["+i+"]"));
            }
        }

        mylist=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);




        /*Intent intent=getIntent();
        if(Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction()))
        {
            String query=intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
            loadHistory(query);
        }*/
    }


    @Override
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.searchable, menu);
        this.menu=menu;
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
        {
            SearchManager manager=(SearchManager)getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
            SearchView search=(SearchView)menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
            search.setSearchableInfo(manager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
            //search.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
            search.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListener(){

                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    loadHistory(query);
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "text changed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return false;
                }



            });
        }
        return true;
    }

    //History
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public void loadHistory(final String query1)
    {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
        {
            String[] columns=new String[]{"_id","text"};
            Object[] temp=new Object[]{"0","default"};
            final MatrixCursor cursor=new MatrixCursor(columns);
            for(int i=0;i<items.size();i++)
            {
                temp[0]=i;
                temp[1]=items.get(i);

                cursor.addRow(temp);

            }
        SearchManager manager=(SearchManager)getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        final SearchView search=(SearchView)menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();

        search.setSuggestionsAdapter(new ExampleAdapter(getBaseContext(),cursor,items));
    mylist.setAdapter(new ExampleAdapter(getBaseContext(),cursor,items));


        }
    }

}
```

**ExampleAdapter.java**

```
package com.example.searchviewdemo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ExampleAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    private List<String> items;
    private TextView text;



    public ExampleAdapter(Context context,Cursor cursor,List<String> items)
    {
        super(context,cursor,false);
        //this.items=new ArrayList<String>();
        Log.e("msg","example adapter is called");
        this.items=items;
    }


    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("position"+cursor.getPosition()+":"+items.get(cursor.getPosition()));
        text.setText(items.get(cursor.getPosition()));

    }
    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("new view is called");
        LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
        text=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.item);
        return view;
    }
![This is my output][1]
}
```

My list values are (two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight)
I am doing something wrong but don't know what i am doing wrong.
Please anyone help to solve this issue

**My launcher activity**

```
package com.example.searchviewdemo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button button1;
    List<String> items=null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        items=new ArrayList<String>();

        //items.add("one");
        items.add("two");
        items.add("three");
        items.add("four");
        items.add("five");
        items.add("six");
        items.add("seven");
        items.add("eight");

        button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,SearchableActivity.class);
                for(int i=0;i<items.size();i++)
                {
                    intent.putExtra("values["+i+"]", items.get(i));
                }

                startActivity(intent);

            }

        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

**Edited searchacivity**

```
SearchManager manager=(SearchManager)getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        final SearchView search=(SearchView)menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();

        List<String> newlist=new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i=0;i<items.size();i++)
        {
            if(items.get(i).toString().trim().equals(query1))
            {
                newlist.add(items.get(i));
            }
        }

        search.setSuggestionsAdapter(new ExampleAdapter(getBaseContext(),cursor,newlist));
```

Comment: I think Set the adapter in searchableActivity file please see the last lines in that file

Comment: where is your Launcher activity ??

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Now i edit my question with launcher activity@jitendra parmer

Comment: i have seen your code when any character or word type in search view the adapter fill all the items. (means all) not the searchable item.

Comment: so, exactly what u want only searchable item fit into adapter ??

Comment: or other then please explain it

Comment: when any character or word type in search view the dropdown list is shown with 7 empty rows that is the each row doesn't contain any text(item name)@jitendra parmar

Comment: okk....your problem is resolved..

Comment: Just change the text color other then BLACK because your searchview is BLACK so list text is not visible

Comment: text.setTextColor(Color.RED);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**try this way may this help you**

**@Edit 2**

```
public void loadHistory(final String query1) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        String[] columns = new String[] { "_id", "text" };
        Object[] temp = new Object[] { "0", "default" };
        MatrixCursor cursor1 = null;
        final MatrixCursor cursor = new MatrixCursor(columns);
        for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
            temp[0] = i;
            temp[1] = items.get(i);
            cursor.addRow(temp);
            try {
                if (items.get(i).startsWith(query1) && query1.length()>0 &&  !query1.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                    suggestionItems.add(items.get(i));
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        // HashSet for not add Duplicate Value in List
        HashSet<String> listToSet = new HashSet<String>(suggestionItems);
        ArrayList<String> nameWithoutDuplicate = new ArrayList<String>(
                listToSet);
        List<String> suggestionName = nameWithoutDuplicate;

        suggestionItems = suggestionName;

        final SearchView search = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search)
                .getActionView();


        cursor1 = new MatrixCursor(columns);
        if (suggestionItems.size() > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < suggestionItems.size(); i++) {
                if (suggestionItems.get(i) != null) {
                    temp[0] = i;
                    temp[1] = suggestionItems.get(i);
                    cursor1.addRow(temp);
                }
            }
            search.setSuggestionsAdapter(new ExampleAdapter(
                    getBaseContext(), cursor1, suggestionItems));
        }
        mylist.setAdapter(new ExampleAdapter(getBaseContext(), cursor,
                items));
    }
}
```

Comment: @ jitendra parmar thanks for your help. now only the related items are shown in suggestion list. but when i select the item from suggestion list the app will crash. how to dislay the selected item in search widget...

Comment: Thanks for your inspiration.i have done it by setOnSuggestionListener(). am i doing in correct way or not ?@jitendra parmar

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13733460/android-providing-recent-search-suggestions-without-searchable-activity

Comment: The above mentioned link is very useful to me. Thank you so much. you helped me lot. @jitendra parmar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81859/discussion-between-jitendra-parmar-and-asha).

Answer (score 0):

```
  @Override
   public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       System.out.println("position"+cursor.getPosition()+":"+items.get(cursor.getPosit  ion()));
    text.setText(items.get(cursor.getPosition()));
    text.setTextColor(Color.RED);
 }}
```

Comment: Oh thanks @jitendra parmar. Now all items are displayed. But  i want to display only matching searchable items how to do this help me...

Comment: u want to check items arraylist if it searchable item exist then add into setSuggestionsAdapter

Comment: Thank for ur help@jitendra parmar. I will add those items into suggesstionsAdapter.

Comment: not yet completed. I tried but null pointer exception is thrown @jitendra parmar

Comment: i edited my question plz see at the end of my question edited searchactivity. When i run the app i typed a text on search widget it throws the run time exception as java.lang.Indexoutofbounds exception in example adapter class at line text.settext()...@jitendra parmar

Comment: intent.putExtra("values["+i+"]",items.get(i).trim());    items.add(extras.getString("values["+i+"]").trim());

Comment: change this two line and then please check the below new code that i have edit